# Image going off screen on Iphone/Android

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone

I have a page with thumbnails and a larger featured image on the right. When you hover over the thumbnails the featured image switches to the current product. It's working fine on web browsers but my client is telling me the featured image disappears on her Iphone/Android. Anybody know why this might be the case?

Here's the web page example:
http://test.pillarsoflifebook.com/lounge-chairs/classic-lounge-chairs/

Thank you!

Code for thumbnails (only showing 1 but there are multiple divs):

```
<div id="thumbs2" style="float: left; width: 480px; padding-top: 30px;">
<div id="thumbs2" style="float: left; text-align: center; height: 175px; width: 160px;"><img alt="26W x 34.5D x 37H" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Ansel_Lounge-Chair.jpg" height="110" />
Ansel</div>
</div>
```

Code for featured image:

```
<div id="tablebasesright" style="float: left; text-align: center; padding-top: 29px;">
<div style="position: fixed; top: 275px;"><img id="largeImage2" alt="26W x 34.5D x 37H" src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Ansel_Lounge-Chair.jpg" height="250" />
<div class="prodName" style="margin-left: 25px;">Ansel</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code here. Then others can view your code & give you a solution.

Comment: Play around on a desktop browser while adjusting the browser window size. You can replicate the faulty behavior that way. That's a start!

Comment: I added the code. It's pretty simple. I'm wondering if I need to do some CSS for mobile?